# C# Faster way to filter for loop with array of int as index?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance

Sorry if this is a duplicate, first question here...

I wanna operate on a large array of structs called notes.
But I don't wanna operate on every element of notes. I'm trying to use a `filter` of an int array (`int[]`) as to skip quite a few of it as shown in below code.

```
Note[] notes = new Note[]
{ 
   // Struct stuff ... 
};

int[] filter = new int[]{ 4,20,50,367... };

for (int i = 0; i < notes.Length; i++)
{
     bool flag = false;
     for (int j = 0; j < filter.Length; j++)
     {
          if (i == filter[j])
          {
               flag = true;
               break;
          }
      }

      if (flag) continue;
      // Do something on notes[i]
}
```

The problem is, the code will run **really slow** (I think) when both notes array and filter array expands.
So, is there a better and **faster way** to do this? Note that the size of filter can be anything based on other conditions

Comment: Typo? Do you mean `if (notes[i] == filter[j])` instead of `if (i == filter[j])`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko no not typo, I'm using the index to filter notes[i], but if it's ```if (notes[i] == filter[j])```  shouldn't it cause an error since (struct == int)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get rid of *inner loop* with a help of `HashSet<int>` while having a better `O(|filter| + |notes|)` *time complexity* instead of initial `O(|filter| * |notes|)`:

```
Note[] notes = new Note[] { 
  ... //Struct stuff 
};

int[] filter = new int[] { 
  4, 20, 50, 367... 
};

HashSet<int> toExclude = new HashSet<int>(filter);

for (int i = 0; i < notes.Length; i++) {
  if (toExclude.Contains(i)) // O(1) time complexity 
    continue;

  //Do something on notes[i] 
}
```

Comment: Do you really claim `HashSet.Contains()` has a complexity of **O(1)**? It will only perform better on larger sets, it will still trend somewhere towards log n

Comment: @Raul Sebastian: it depends on `GetHashCode` implementation; Microsoft one is good enough if items are random in `filter`. Sure an *adversary* can such items such that we have a lot of hash collistions and inefficient `toExclude.Contains`

Comment: **@Dmitry Bychenko** Thanks for making me look it up. It really seems that HashSet lookups complexity stays constant, while in worst case it would be linear.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter the notes using Linq like this:

```
Note[] notes = new Note[]{ ...//Struct stuff };
int[] filter = new int[]{ 4,20,50,367... };

var filteredNotes = notes.ToList().Where(note => !filter.Contains(note.Id)).ToList();

foreach(var note in filteredNotes)
{
//Do something on note
}
```

You would need to test the performance though, as Linq tends to be slow in specific circumstances.

Comment: Ermm, actually, this is exactly the opposite I want to do since my filter means "skip this"

Comment: Sorry, but it seams that we should iterate all indexes, *but* filter (i.e. `0, 1, 2, 3, 5,...19, 21, ...`). Please, note `if (flag) continue;` in the code provided

Comment: @TheSorrowRaven sorry, I misunderstood you then. Let me edit it

Comment: Final materialization `.ToList()` is *redundant*: `foreach` will do with `IEnumerable<Node>`

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the filter array and create a new boolean array that has all elements you want to skip as true.

```
bool[] filterArray= new bool[notes.Length];
foreach(var index in filter)
{
   if(index<filterArray.Length)
       filterArray[index]=true;
}
```

Then you have to just check the index of this array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < notes.Length; i++)
{
     if(!filterArray[i]){
     //Do something on notes[i]
     }

}
```

The complexity of this code will be `O(m+n*X)` where `m` is the length of the filter array, `n` the length of the node array and `X` the complexity of your operation on `notes[i]`. Assuming mO(n*X).

Your complexity now is `O(m*n*X)`